# How to change the text color of sherlock actionbar overflow-dropdown item in android?

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, actionbarsherlock, android-styles

Here is how I'm changing the background color of sherlock actionbar overflow-dropdown menu. How can I change the dropdown item text color and gravity? Please help me. Currently the text color is black. [image]

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.ForceOverflow">

</style>
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">  
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/CustomActionOverFlowStyle</item>
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/CustomActionOverFlowStyle</item>
    <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/CustomActionButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/CustomActionButtonStyle</item>
     <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/CustomDropDownListView</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/CustomDropDownListView</item>

</style>

<style name="CustomDropDownListView" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:background">@color/abs__bright_foreground_disabled_holo_dark</item> <!-- this works -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item> <!-- but this is not working -->
    <item name="android:divider">@color/app_bg_color</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">0.5dp</item>
    <item name="android:dividerPadding">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">right</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally solved in this way.  However, I didn't test impact on other widgets on ActionBar:

```
<item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/CustomActionOverflowDropDownText</item>
<item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/CustomActionOverflowDropDownText</item>
```

and

```
<style name="CustomActionOverflowDropDownText" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/app_bg_color</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">right</item>
</style>
```